# how do i get the collection of components placed on the form to change their font

Tags: c#

i want to get the collection of all components in the form and change the font through code. how to do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the [`Controls`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls.aspx) property to access all controls on a form.