# Set same fonts to all the similar controls in a Project

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, controls

Is there a way to set similar fonts for all the similar type of controls of Windows Forms appearing in a project.

For e.g I want to set all the **textboxes** in project to **Arial Black 10pt Regular** and all the **labels** to **Arial Black 10pt Bold**, so on and so forth.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Avoid your users hating you, let the OS default the font, and font-size. In short: Don't edit anything but the style (Bold/Normal).

Comment: @Claus: I want to use special UI Fonts (Segoe UI) which makes the application look much better. You are right that I must not irritate user by using **too fancy** fonts

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do i get the collection of components placed on the form to change their font](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549108/how-do-i-get-the-collection-of-components-placed-on-the-form-to-change-their-font)

Comment: @Niraj: Your notion of "better looking" is completely subjective. That's what computer settings are for: Configure your computer to use that font as the default font and give other users the same freedom.

Comment: @Daniel: Point to be noted. Thanks

Comment: Windows Forms in VS2008 DO NOT use the system font by default - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297701/default-font-for-windows-forms-application

Comment: @Stuart Oh, One gets to use to the awesomeness of WPF, I guess ;)

Answer (score 0):

1: Create a Base Control that inherits from TextBox.

Then make all your controls inherit from it.

2: Make a Base Form that inherits from Form.

Make a simple loop in the beginning that loops through all the controls in the form recursively, and changes the font.

Then make all your forms inherit from that base form.

Comment: Yes but then looping through the controls would be much easier using the `Control` class.